# Center an image when displayed on a mobile device in HTML - inline

Tags: html, css

So below is this table. It essentially creates a grid of images that goes into an email. because it is an email I need the styling to be `in-line`. The grid looks great on a desktop but when viewed on a mobile device each table aligns to the left leaving a white space to the right. however, if I change the align tag, the grid no longer works on desktop.

Is there a way with `in-line` stylings to either get the content to align to the center when viewed on mobile only Or at least get the table to fill the container when viewed on a smaller screen?

````
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <tr><td align="left" style=" border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif"  valign="top">
                
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif"><tbody><tr><td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif" valign="top"> 
                
              <img  style="border:0;height:auto;outline:none;text-decoration:none;margin:0;display:block;padding:0!important" width="226" src="#">          
              </tr></td></tbody></table>
                
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif"><tbody><tr><td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif" valign="top">
              <img  style="border:0;height:auto;outline:none;text-decoration:none;margin:0;display:block;padding:0!important" width="226"  src="#" /></tr></td></tbody></table>
              
              <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif"><tbody><tr><td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif" valign="top">
              
              <img  style="border:0;height:auto;outline:none;text-decoration:none;margin:0;display:block;padding:0!important" width="226"  src="#" /></tr></td></tbody></table>         
            </td>
          </tr>
        
        <tr><td align="left" style=" border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif"  valign="top">
                
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif"><tbody><tr><td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif" valign="top">
                         
              <img  style="border:0;height:auto;outline:none;text-decoration:none;margin:0;display:block;padding:0!important" width="226" src="#">
              </tr></td></tbody></table>
                
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif"><tbody><tr><td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif" valign="top">
              <img style="border:0;height:auto;outline:none;text-decoration:none;margin:0;display:block;padding:0!important" width="226"  src="#" /></tr></td></tbody></table>
              
              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif"><tbody><tr><td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Archivo',Arial,sans-serif" valign="top">
              
              <img style="border:0;height:auto;outline:none;text-decoration:none;margin:0;display:block;padding:0!important" width="226"  src="#" /></tr></td></tbody></table>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the table is so important to use ,

but you can do this by simply put the images in  for example and the div style will be:

```
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: '100[%,vw]'; // may not necessary
}
```

css flex is so important for responsive design.

if not, put your table within div and give the style to the div

mobile device size (width) is generaly <= 768px (without resolution)